# C#- Line break instead of comma-separated-values in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataTable` which is populated from database. In one of its column i have comma separated values. I want to remove comma and put the line break so that when i bind it to the `GridView` it shows line breaks instead of comma seperated values.

Comment: Can you perhaps take a screen shot of this grid so that I can personally see what the DataGridView looks like..?

Comment: A grid view in which context? `WinForms`? `WPF`? `ASP.NET`?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: not able to place an image since a new user.

Comment: (Totally unrelated), you have one of the most unique user IDs in [so]. 2000000. Congrats :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach for an ASP.NET `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Values">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" id="Values" 
                Text='<%# string.Join("<br />", Eval("Values").ToString().Split(new []{","},StringSplitOptions.None)) %>'>
            </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Bound a `DataTable` with some numbers to it, here's the result:

[image]

Of yourse it's also possible to use a nested `GridView` and bind it in `RowDataBound` of the outer grid. But that's a more difficult approach with some drawbacks which might be too much in this case.

Comment: Helpful, my exact requirement as well., Thanks Tim

Answer (score 2):

Try the below...

If it is windows Application then try the below...

```
yourString = yourString.Replace(",",System.Environment.NewLine)
```